# How does earth (multivariate adaptive regression splines) handle categorical predictors?

Tags: r, regression, splines, mars

I wanted to understand more about whether my implementation of the multivariate adaptive regression splines is correct. I have crop yield data from multiple locations and year and I want to predict yield as a function of location, year and some climate variables.

Before running mars (from earth package), I converted location and year as factors in R

```
dat$year <- as.factor(dat$year)
dat$location.id <- as.factor(dat$location.id)
```

I also converted yield values into log to avoid negative prediction

```
 dat$log.yld <- log(dat$yld)
```

And then fitted my model:

```
earth(x = dat[,index of predictors that include climate + loc + year],
      y = dat[,65], # position of my log yield values
      degree =2, 
      pmethod = "cv",
      nfold = 10,
      ncross = 3)
```

Is my implementation above is correct? How does earth handle categorical predictors like I have with location and year?

Thank you

Comment: General comment: It's always good to determine the sample size required for a method to yield reliable results.  MARS requires a much greater sample size than a parametric model if the parametric model  is known not to need many interaction terms.

Answer (score 0):

The factors are expanded (into dummy variables ) before being fed to the algorithm
http://www.milbo.org/doc/earth-notes.pdf

Comment: please add full reference for your link and summarize why it supports your answer